# Refreshing cache is necessary to see the results of a controller action (delete)

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers, full-page-cache, caching

I have a table of data, I added a delete button in each row. The controller action is well executed and the row is deleted, but I need to **manually refresh Magento cache** (FullPageCache to be precise) to see the results. How to manage to see instantly the results without having to manually refresh the cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup following step in your controller.
**1. Define constructor – pass Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface and Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool to your file’s constructor as defined below :**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}
```

**2. Now add following code to the method where you want clear/flush cache**

```
$types=array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }
    foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
```

that's it.